# Does a CSS transition effect on HTML links slow down page transitions on click?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-transitions, transition

I found this snippet in the CSS for my website:

```
a {
    transition: 0.25s;
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what it does, but I'm afraid that it is adding a quarter second delay when somebody clicks a link to get to the next page.  Should I remove it for performance reasons?

Comment: Er... http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/03/18/css-animations-and-transitions-performance/

Comment: @PraveenKumar That looks like a good overview of CSS transitions performance in general, but I don't see that it addresses transition effects on links specifically.

Comment: It wont have any effect on the click event. Transitions effect _CSS_.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller That's why I was not sure... `:)`

Comment: @Turnip So if it doesn't have any effect, I can just safely remove it?   Why would it be there then?

Comment: Stephen if you not heed visual presentation, you should remove it another things if you use a frame work trasitions effect the performance of SPA completely.

Comment: @AhsN that isn't correct. This code could be effecting any property defined for links else where in the CSS. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3w388nbk/1/

Comment: @Turnip I think that is it!  It is doing a delay for the `:hover` color change.   Can you put that in as an answer and explain that it doesn't effect the transition that I was assuming, but rather a different one?

Comment: I think @JakeRowsell 's answer covers it. Accept his

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS transations cannot effect the transitions between pages.   They can only effect the visual effects on the page itself.

In this case it is likely making the color change when you hover over a link be softer and not instantaneous.  The following code snipped demonstrates it with a longer 2 second delay to make it more obvious.

```css
a {
  transition: 2s;
  color: blue;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover over this link</a>
```

If that is indeed the case, it would be safer to specify the exact effects on which the transform is to apply.  [Kamuran Sönecek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4766521/kamuran-s%c3%b6necek) points out in his answer that those can be a performance problem when the link changes size and forces a page reflow.  `color`, and `background-color`, are the ones that it is likely targeting.  It would be safer to make sure that the transition is only applied to those items.

Specifying the transition-property, would also be clearer where it applied.   I would probably not have asked this question to begin with if it was clear which transitions it applied to.

```css
a {
  transition: color, background-color, 2s;
  color: blue;
  background-color: white;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover over this link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS affects visual presentation of DOM elements on the page. The transition property will be applied to CSS changes (for instance to fade, grow/shrink). Clicking a link is outside the scope of CSS and will not cause a delay. The delay is purely to the effect being applied.

Comment: If it doesn't effect the page transition on click what could it be doing?

Comment: It would just be a general CSS statement. Rather than saying 'transition for height', 'transition for width', 'transition for colour' you say a more general 'transition'. As far as I know usually you'd say transition: all 0.25s; (not sure if omitting it is fine) which would apply all CSS changes with the transition. Page navigation does not have any connection with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Some transitions effect performance. I faced a performance problem when we built our last SPA project.

Your CSS snippet will effect all `a` elements when any style property changes on them.

```
div {transition: 2s;height:100px;background:#f00;width:100px}
```

If you were to use this CSS snippet all changes would be done with animation: background, height, width, text color, etc.

Here is the example:

```js
var width = 100;
function myFunc(){
    width += 100;
    document.getElementById("teest").style.width = width + "px";
    document.getElementById("teest").style.background = '#FF9' + width;
}
setInterval(myFunc,2000);
```

```css
* {transition: 2s}
div {height:100px;background:#f00}
#teest { width:100px}
```

```html
<div id="teest"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it could effect performance, but only of on page rendering.  It isn't adding 250ms to each click like I was afraid that it might.

Comment: I updated my own answer to this question because of this to suggest that that the transition should be moved to the `a:hover` which would limit its scope more.